# Add & Update custom field values of sales form In QBOL

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using V3 QBOL API consolibyte PHP API to sync Data with QBOL Canadian version.
I add a custom field in Invoices and Now I want to Add/Update this custom filed value through my PHP code.
I fetch this custom field value in PHP code.
problem is that, after adding custom field in QBOL, my PHP code for update invoice gives error

**10000: [An application error has occurred while processing your request, System Failure Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{-1}"]**

although I don't change any thing in invoice and if I unset the Customfield

```
$Invoice->unsetCustomField();
```

then invoice update successfully.
My php code to update custome field is

```
$CustomField = $Invoice->getCustomField('0');
$CustomField->setStringValue('Test value here');
```

Here first i get custom field object and then set StringValue.

I also try

```
$Invoice->setCustomField($CustomField);
```

but in both cases invoice update gives error as shown above.

I think, I am missing some thing that goes wrong.
Please try to identify error and guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the latest code from GitHub? Can you post the output of print($Invoice->lastRequest()); so we can help you troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

You're using outdated code.

If you grab the latest code from GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

This will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for consideration. My code is not outdated but I am missing something that was going wrong. Missing thing was the custom field property "DefinitionId". There is a need to set the "DefinitionId"   $CustomField->setDefinitionId('1');    in update case otherwise it's value is going with minus sign that create error.

Comment: @Hashim Are you *positive* you have the latest code? You should not need to set DefinitionId if you have the latest code. Can you email me the XML like I asked previously at support [at] consolibyte [dot] com so we can look into further?

Comment: Please check email "support@consolibyte.com". I send an email that contain the invoice Update last request XML